# Fengyuanchen Datapicker - arrows prev/next

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to make datapicker with arrows prev/next. Inline version is working. But i want to make input with buttons with data-view prev/next month(like in inline version).

HTML

```
<div class="match__arrows">
  <button class="match__arrow match__prev" data-view="month prev">Prev</button>

  <input class="datapicker" data-toggle="datepicker">

  <button class="match__arrow match__next" data-view="month next">Next</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
  autoPick: true,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  language: 'en-EN'
});
```

JS library: 
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to have a global variable, you can open the calendar with an offset to the date:

This is a version with [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) now that [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) is in maintenance mode:

```js
currDate = DateTime.local();

document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  currDate = currDate.plus({months:1});
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker('setDate', currDate);
});

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  currDate = currDate.minus({months:1});
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker('setDate', currDate);
});

$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
              autoPick: true,
              format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
              language: 'en-EN'
            });
```

You'll need to add [moment js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js) for date manipulation, so you don't end up with weird things happening.

```
currDate = moment();
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  currDate.add(1, 'months');
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker('setDate', currDate.toDate());
});

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  currDate.add(-1, 'months');
  $('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker('setDate', currDate.toDate());
});

$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
          autoPick: true,
          format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
          language: 'en-EN'
        });
```

Comment: I forgot to write a library. Which I use. https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/ I tried edit it, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ah, well, that would be because jquery's datepicker's API is different to the plugin you're using. You should edit your question to state the precise datepicker you're using.

Comment: Well, i did it. Sorry.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I've added moment.js because manipulating dates in JS is tricky. Hopefully this will work for you.